# VB.Net automate flash in WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, flash, browser, sh

I've passed many hours searching the web for a solution to something which seems obvious, but without results.

1. I need to automate a task in a Flash application running on my intranet.

   - I can't change the Flash application nor do I have access to the source code.
   - it's not a Flash movie but an application.
   - I can't download the swf.
2. I'm using a WebBrowser in a form. The Flash app is displaying without issues.
3. So far, I have been able to automate the task (clicking on some buttons, then inputting text and finally saving the results on a server). It works but it's not clean at all because I use hard-coded timers to wait a given action is done and then I click on very specific point at given coordinates in the application.

What I would like to do:

Avoid hard-coded timers. the Flash application takes some time to display all elements on the window (from 20 to 60+ sec). I would like to be able to detect when all elements are loaded. I tried to retrieve the text of the windows handle, but while I can retrieve the Flash `hwnd`, I can't retrieve the content (through messages).

In brief, instead of waiting 60sec (and not being 100% sure it's enough), if the last element to load in the Flash app has "ABC" written in it, I would like to detect it's displayed so that I can continue the sequence (click on the next button).

I'm using VB.net. Any hints to achieve that would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody with the same issue ? this is so strange... Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Lol. I am trying to do the same thing but with no results. You can try to see if there are POST/GET codes that can help you if the application has an online nature. Other than that you can only simulate clicks, because flash can't be easily interacted with. This is why most of the things are going to swap with HTML5 now.